# Stop kendoUI Editor from inserting inline styling

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui

I am using kendo web editor for one of my projects and having an issue which is that `kendoUI Editor` unnecessarily apply a lot of inline styling to the tags in the text.

For example:

```
<p style="margin-bottom:1em;padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;font-size:14px;clear:both;word-wrap:break-word;color:#000000;font-family:Arial, 'Liberation Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;line-height:18px;">The default MVC template puts the Web.config at the root of the project.</p>
```

I don't need this inline styling as I am handling the styling of my objects through one style sheet.

Is there a way I can stop this from happening and can only limit the editor to insert basic tags in the text?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? What isn't working? Is it adding the inline styles to the actual text you can copy and paste? Can you post a jsfiddle or something please?